# Read Word from a Unicode Line instead of Char

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, unicode

I have the below code:

```
for line in contentText:
          print type(line), #-> o/p is unicode
          word = line.strip().split()
          print word, #-> o/p is <type 'list'>
          print type(word),
```

when I do `line.strip().split()`, the each char is getting displayed.

For example, if my line is "*Read Word from a Unicode Line instead of Char*", then o/p is:
R
e
a
d

w
o
r
d

a
.
.
so on

I want to read it as 'Read', 'word', from as words and not by char for further processing..

How can I achieve that?

Also how can I remove white-spaces for further processing?

Comment: this `for i in line.strip().split(): print i` works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterating a string yields single-character strings:

```
>>> text = 'Read word'
>>> for x in text:
...     print x
... 
R
e
a
d

w
o
r
d
```

Split first to get a list of words, then iterate the list:

```
>>> text.split()  # str.split remove space characters
['Read', 'word']
```

---

```
>>> for x in text.split():
...     print x
... 
Read
word
```

Comment: So basically you are asking me to put " for line in contentText?"

Comment: No; if `contentText` is a string, not a list of strings, don't loop over it at all.

Comment: @tripleee I am newbee and little confused here. So what you are stating is contentText is a string. So in that string is entire line stored:

"Read Word from a Unicode Line instead of Char" is a string and if I loop over it , it is going to read every char R e a d separately but not as word Read Word. So for that I split and it splits based on spaces?

Comment: @Dinakar, You understand right. That's what I said in the answer.